# Converting wchar_t to Char

Tags: c#, char, pinvoke, marshalling, wchar-t

I need to convert:

```
wchar_t arr[20][32]
```

To

```
char arr[20][32]
```

The conversion is done in the DLL (written in C++) and I want the values of `arr` to be displayed to the user in Windows Forms (written in C#).

Is it possible to display directly `wchar_t` in a textbox or should I convert from `wchar_t` to `char` in the DLL and then from `char` to `string` in Windows Forms?

How is this conversion done?

Comment: Look into Marshal.Copy on MSDN (from the C# side).  I don't know the answer to whether you should convert the string on one side or the other, though.

Answer (score 1):

If the conversion is being done in C++, then take a look at WideCharToMultibyte function, defined in  and exported from kernel32

If the conversion is being done in C#, look at the System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string) function to get an ASCII representation of a unicode string.